# If a function $f(x)$ has an extreme value on $x=k$, $f''(k) \ne 0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

This is a additional question to : [About extreme values of $\{f(x)-x\}^2$ when $f(x)$ is a cubic function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4499819/about-extreme-values-of-fx-x-2-when-fx-is-a-cubic-function)

In the original post, the main objective was to clarify conditions of where do extreme values of $\{f(x)-x\}^2$ occur.

My idea was, if the function is denoted by $h(x)$, it must be $h'(k)=0$ and $h''(k)\ne 0$ for some $x=k$ in order to make an extreme value on those points.

By this logic, there was a function in the original post, $f(x) = \frac{1}{48}x^3 + \frac{3}{4}x + \frac{1}{3}$. And for such $f(x)$, I didn't think $\{f(x)-x\}^2$ has an extreme value on $x=2$ because both derivative and second derivative was $0$.

But it seems like it does have one, according to
[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=extrema+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22GlobalExtremaCalculator%22%2C+%22curvefunction%22%7D+-%3E%22%28%281%2F6%29%281%2F8+x%5E3+%2B+36%2F8+x+%2B+2%29-x%29%5E2%22).

So my question is, is the logic "in order to be an extreme value, $f' = 0$ and $f'' \ne 0$" is false? And if it is, what is the correct logic of it?

Comment: Clarification requested:  Is $y = x^4$ a counter example to the question presented in this postings title?  That is, am I interpreting the question correctly?

Comment: @user2661923 yes, it can be counter example.

Comment: Does this mean that the underlying question in your posting has been answered?

Comment: @user2661923 I can see that my logic was totally wrong, but do I have to manually check if the +/- changes near $f'(k)$ to check if it is an extreme?

Comment: My exposure to Calculus is somewhat superficial.  Someone with a deeper knowledge may be able to respond better to your posting.  Personally, while I have seen theory around what happens if $f'(x_0) = 0$ and $f''(x_0) \neq 0,$ I have never seen theory around what happens if $f'(x_0) = 0$ and $f''(x_0) = 0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $f(x)=a \pm (x-k)^4$, we have local minimum/maximum $f(k)=a$ and $f'(k)=f''(k)=f'''(k)=0$. When $f(x)=a \pm |x-k|$, we have local minimum/maximum $f(k)=a$ and undefined $f'(k)$.

If $f'(k)=f''(k)=...=f^{(n-1)}(k)=0$ and $f^{(n)} \ne 0$ then $f(k)$ is extremum in $k$ if and only if $n$ is even number (it makes direction of variation change). Does not apply to the reciprocal because of undefined values cases, non-continuity of functions...

Rule (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima#Definition): if exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $\forall x \in [x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon], f(k)>f(x)$ then $k$ is a strict local maximum point of $f$, therefore $f(k)$ is its local maximum function value, and the minimum rule is like it but $f(k)<f(x)$.